# Как вывести в цикле список таблиц из базы данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.

Есть БД с таблицами и подключение к ней. Название и количество таблиц заранее не известно. Есть ли способ вывести в цикле список таблиц из базы данных mysql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_list_tables($dbname); 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
       echo $row[0]."<br>";
```

Ну есть же стандартные функции, почему никто мануалы не читает?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_query=$mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES FROM `MySqlDB` LIKE '%';");

while ($row=$sql_query->fetch_array()){
    echo "$row[0]</br>";
}
```

DB и паттерн LIKE'a подставить свои.fetch можно брать любой: row, array, assoc